# how to pass in a string the value of a pointer to pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

For example I have a( char ** ptr) which includes the address of a string.

I want to put this string in a new string ptr_2 .

It is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are many, many ways in which you can screw it up, though.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it this way: when you put an asterisk in front of a pointer, you remove an asterisk from the type of the result:

```
ptr is char**
*ptr is char*
**ptr is char
```

String in C is char*, so you need to use *ptr.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy(ptr_2, *ptr)` should do the trick.

`*ptr` gets the address of the string you want to copy and from there you can manipulate it with any of the usual string handling functions.

Comment: or `ptr_2 = strdup(*ptr);` or simply `ptr_2 = *ptr;`

Comment: @harp: don't forget to upvote and accept helpful questions and answers :)